# How to manage access control with roles to not allow a basic user to be able to update an account which is not owned

Tags: node.js, jwt, access-control

In my NodeJS API, I implemented roles using this npm pkg `accesscontrol` and I also used `JWT` for the token part. My issue is that I'm unable to limit the basic role user to update an account which is not his/her own. What I would like to achieve is that Admin can do whatever he wants but the other roles as basic are restricted. 
In my case, I want the user with the basic role to be able to update only its owned account but not any other else but now that is not working.

In my Postman what I'm doing is calling the update endpoint with the token of the basic role and trying to update a userId which is not associated with the token. What I should see is a message that says `You don't have enough permission to perform this action` but instead I'm able to update.

The roles I used this PKG [AccessControl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accesscontrol)

```
// Access controls roles
const AccessControl = require("accesscontrol");

let grantsObject = {
    admin: {
        user: {
            "create:any": ["*"],
            "read:any": ["*"],
            "update:any": ["*"],
            "delete:any": ["*"]
        }
    },
    basic: {
        user: {
            "create:own": ["*"],
            "read:own": ["*"],
            "update:own": ["*"],
            "delete:own": ["*"],
        }
    }
};

// Init
const accessCtrl = new AccessControl();

// Roles access
// Here adding the access rules and to what we give access to a specific role
// Basic, Moderator, Admin
// Admin => Read/Write full powers
// Moderator => Read access everywhere
// Basic => Read/write own information
exports.roles = (() => {
    accessCtrl.setGrants(grantsObject);

    return accessCtrl;
})();
```

My route

```
// PUT update user
router.put(
    "/:userId",
    Auth.allowIfLoggedin,
    Auth.grantAccess("updateOwn", "user"),
    UserCtrl.updateUser
);
```

Middleware used:

```
/ Allowing access to right role permission
const grantAccess = (action, resource) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            console.log(req.user.role);
            // Permission to perform the specified action of the provided resource
            const permission = Roles.roles.can(req.user.role)[action](resource);
            // No permission => 401
            if (!permission.granted) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    401,
                    "You don't have enough permission to perform this action"
                );
            }
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    };
};

// Allow if user logged in
const allowIfLoggedin = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log("LOCALS", JSON.stringify(res.locals));
        const user = res.locals.loggedInUser;
        if (!user)
            throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                401,
                "You need to be logged in to perform this operation"
            );
        // User
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

module.exports = { grantAccess, allowIfLoggedin };
```

Controller

```
// UPDATE user
    async updateUser(req, res, next) {
        try {
            // Check empty req.body
            if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(500, "Nothing to update");
            }
            // Body to update
            const update = req.body;
            // UserId to update
            const userId = req.params.userId;
            // Finding the user to update
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, update);
            // Updated user
            const user = await User.findById(userId);
            // Response
            res.status(200).json({
                user: user,
                message: "User has been updated"
            });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Since You should use `updateAny` instead of `updateOwn`. The idea behind this trick is you let `admin role` with full power to access this route then add conditions to check for other small cases such as `user` update his/her own data.

```js
router.put(
    "/:userId",
    Auth.allowIfLoggedin,
    // Use updateAny instead of updateOwn
    Auth.grantAccess("updateAny", "user"),
    UserCtrl.updateUser
);
```

Then, check for `userId` in `grantAccess` function as below.

```js
// Allowing access to right role permission
const grantAccess = (action, resource) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const modifiedAction = action;
            // Check for userId and modify action from updateAny to updateOwn
            // when current user updates his/her own info
            if (req.user.userId === req.params.userId) {
                modifiedAction = action.replace('Any', 'Own');
            }

            // Permission to perform the specified action of the provided resource
            const permission = Roles.roles.can(req.user.role)[modifiedAction](resource);
            // No permission => 401
            if (!permission.granted) {
                throw new ErrorHandlers.ErrorHandler(
                    401,
                    "You don't have enough permission to perform this action"
                );
            }
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    };
};
```

You can check out another great video about authorization [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jI4K7L-LI58).

Comment: [@Anh Nhat Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8546128/anh-nhat-tran) Somehow you solved my problem thank a lot, Love you :)